# Multi node kafka cluster: Producer and Consumer not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a kafka cluster consisting of two machines. This is my server.properties:

```
broker.id=2
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://a.b.c.d:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=2
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=a.b.c.d:2181,a.b.c.e:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

And this is my zookeeper.properties:

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=0
tickTime=2000
server.1=a.b.c.d:2888:3888
server.2=a.b.c.e:2888:3888
initLimit=20
syncLimit=10
```

a.b.c.d = The IPs these machines have, e.g. 192.168.....

I start the zookeeper server on both machines using:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start config/zookeeper.properties
```

I then start kafka servers on both the nodes. After this, I am able to create a new topic and get its details using --describe. However I am unable to read from consumer or write to producer. I run these by:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server a.b.c.d:9092,a.b.c.e:9092 --topic randomTopic --from beginning

bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list a.b.c.d:9092,a.b.c.e:9092 --topic randomTopic
```

When I run the producer, the prompt(>) appears and I can write into it. However, kafka cannot read anything from the consumer and the screen remains black.

How do I make the consumer read the data in the topics or make producer able to write the data in the topics?

Comment: I see `someTopic` in the consumer command and `randomTopic` in the producer. Also both commands have different kafka endpoints. Are these typos ?

Comment: Both of them were typos. Corrected.

Comment: `um.partitions=2` - seems to be another typo?

Comment: Corrected. It was num.partitions. However, there were no typos in the code/commands that I used.

Comment: there is a small typo: `--from-beginning` instead of `--from beginning`. Won't solve your problem of course. I kind of could reproduce your  issue, and then not anymore. When I was reproducing your issue, it looked like using only a single server in `--broker-list` made things better. Not sure why. Give it a try?

Comment: @ChristopheSchmitz How is using a single server different than using both of them? What difference does it make?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I wrote "Not sure why". Did you try? If this fix your issue, then we can start to think about the "why"

Comment: The thing worked as it is after restarting the server. :/ I think I should delete this question.